# Javascript prototype scoping and recursion issue

Tags: javascript, recursion, prototype, concatenation

So I think I've fallen off a cliff in the javascipt scoping and prototype area. I'm attempting to build a simple tree structure out of objects. building the tree is no issue, but when I try to get all the children, I can't seem to concat them together. I've walked though the code and it seems like there is some odd scoping issue that is happening and I can't figure it out. This is the code I have:

```
var Foo = function (value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.children = [];
}

Foo.prototype.getAllChildren = function () {
    var childs = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.children.length; i++) {
        childs.push(this.children[i]);
        childs.concat(this.children[i].getAllChildren());
    }
    return childs;
};

var foo1 = new Foo(1),
    foo2 = new Foo(2),
    foo3 = new Foo(3);

foo1.children.push(foo2);
foo2.children.push(foo3);

var children = foo1.getAllChildren(),
    expected = foo1.children.concat(foo2.children);
```

I've created a fiddle here that shows the results of the code above http://jsfiddle.net/e2zf8/1/

The getAllChildren function only returns a list with one Foo for foo1 when it should return a list of two Foo. (yes Foo is plural for Foo). It seems to have something to do with recursion, scope and prototype scope. I can't seem to pinpoint my mistake and any help (or my problem) would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's neither an issue with scoping nor with your prototype.

Only the [array `concat` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) does not modify the array it's applied on, but returns the concatenated new one. Your code leaves `childs` unaltered. Two possibilities:

- Use `childs = childs.concat(…)` to overwrite `childs` each time with the new array
- push each of the `getAllChildren` to your `childs` array, either by using a loop or `[].push.apply(childs, this.children[i].getAllChildren())`.

Comment: What a huge brain fart. I didn't realize it just returned a copy. I assumed it operated like push. This is actually better than I expected. I'll certainly use overwrite solution. Its just a bit confusing that the certain array methods mutate and some don't.